# how to use dynamic templates in python pyramid

Tags: python, jinja2, pyramid

i've finished developing a website, it's working fine however i am trying to optimize my website by adding dynamic templates, and want to make sure that if it can be done on pyramid python.

for example, in my jinja template i have the following:

```
{% block article_detail %}
    <form action="{{request.route_url('Sports_News_Action',action=action)}}" method="post" class="form">
        {% if action =='edit' %}
            {{ form.id() }}
```

example in my controller:

```
@view_config(route_name='Sports_News_Action', match_param='action=create',
             renderer='StarAdmin:templates/edit_sports.jinja2')
def general_create(request):
    entry = SportNews()
```

the request route will have to match the one in my controller in order to run the function. what i want to do is how do i replace the one in jinja with a dynamic variable, to use the one jinja template lets say for different views/controllers with different route_names.

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, for every function, change the `route_name` arg in the decorator. Else update your question for clarity.

Comment: yes, but what i need to do is have a variable route_name instead of a fixed one, for every form action, i'll need to route it to a specific route upon submission, my question is. how do i use one temple with one action, one submit button for multiple route.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your situation the simplest solution is to leave `action` undefined and the browser will submit the request to the current url. You only need to specify `action` if you want to submit the form to a different url than the current. That being said, you can use lots of different options in pyramid to generate a url as well. For example, `request.url` is the current url, or `request.matched_route.name` is the name of the current matched route.

Comment: Thanks, i actually went back to my code and optimized the pages that needs to be dynamic and was able to do it easily. i guess it was just a matter of getting used to the programming language, and everything else comes naturally after that.